# How to invert multiple y-axis in R highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization, visualization

I want to invert a multiple y-Axis chart in R using highchater library. Unfortunately, when I specify the use `hc_chart(iverted=T)`, it moves one axis, the rest do not move their position. 
Here is an example from jbkunst: https://rpubs.com/jbkunst/create_yaxis

```
library("highcharter");library(dplyr)

highchart() %>%
# probably I should specify "inverted=T" in "hc_yAxis_multiples"
  hc_yAxis_multiples(create_yaxis(naxis = 4, title = list(text = NULL))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(1,3,2)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(20, 40, 10), yAxis = 1) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(200, 400, 500), type = "column", yAxis = 2) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(500, 300, 400), type = "column", yAxis = 2) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(5,4,7), type = "spline", yAxis = 3)
```

Here is an example that I would like to adopt. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cdok7w0L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have multiple y-axes combined with the inverted chart, I suggest defining them manually (without *create_yaxis* method), see:

```
library("highcharter");

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(inverted=T) %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(width = '30%'),
    list(width = '30%', left = '35%', offset = 0),
    list(width = '30%', left = '70%', offset = 0)
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(1,3,2)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(20, 40, 10), yAxis = 1) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(200, 400, 500), type = "column", yAxis = 2)
```

Also, you have a typo in "*hc_chart(inverted=T) %>%*"

In the example you provided in jsFiddle, there are separate containers for each chart. In your example, you have one container but many series connected to a separate axis, so you need to define their width and left offset.

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.width
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.left
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset

Let me know if you have any further questions.